# Uri Class doesn't convert correctly the special char

Tags: c#, url, encoding, xamarin.forms

I'm using the Uri class to request datas using a php script. In my case I need to use URL containing special char like: `é` or `'`. Here is my piece of code:

```
string NomArret = "Université";

uri = new Uri("http://localhost/getdata.php?aarret=" + NomArret);
```

But this return 0 results. I debugged and I notices that uri encode this URL like:

```
http://84.75.112.69/getdata.php?aarret=Universit%C3%A9
```

So he converts the char `é` to `%C3%A9`. In this website ([www.degraeve.com/reference/urlencoding.php](http://www.degraeve.com/reference/urlencoding.php)) I've seen that the `é` char does be convert to `%E9`.

When I try manually using this encoding:

```
http://84.75.112.69/getdata.php?aarret=Universit%E9
```

It works ! So how can I adapt my code to be able to convert correctly the special character ?

Comment: `%C3%A9` is hex, so you could convert the character to hex.

Answer (score 0):

Can you use `Uri.EscapeDataString` ? (I'm not a C# dev so i can't verify it)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/13415261)

Comment: In fact it's an answer because it can be the required function. But yes a correct answer would be "Try to use URI.EscapeDataString". Sorry for that mistake :/